# How to set up conversation history and handle deleted messages

Tags: php, mysql

Backgroun: I'm trying to build a private messaging system in Mysql with conv view.

I have a msg_received tbl which looks like this

```
id   from_member_id  to_member_id   message_id
1    123                 456               101
2    456                 123               102
3    123                 456               103
4    456                 123               103
```

So when userA (id: 123) views his conv history; he sees the 2 messages he has sent to userB (id:456) and and 2 messages he has received from userB (id: 456). So he sees a total of 4 messages. Same for userB; he sees a total of 4 messages.

The problem is that I would like to allow userA to delete one of those messages. Lets say that he wants to delete msg_id 103. So now userA only sees 3 messages.

The problem is that when userB tries to view the conv history; he also sees only 3 messages instead of the 4 that he should. This is because he hasn't deleted any messages and expects to see the full history.

Can you guys provide any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 2 flags: `deleted_by_sender` and `deleted_by_recipient`.

When only one user "deleted" - set up approproate flag. When both flags = 1 - delete the record physically.

Also - now you'll need to add `AND deleted_by_recipient = 0` condition to your `WHERE`

Comment: If we can do this by added only 1 Db table column, then why we should add 2 column? This table is used for chat data, so In future It will have lots of data. At that time this thing will affect.

Comment: @DharmeshGoswami because premature optimisations make very little sense. Until you have performance problem - you should design the most boring and naive way.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to add two columns, for "from_user_deleted" and "to_user_deleted", and then respect those columns when showing the message lists (and clean up when both flags are set.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a column in table named hide_from,

[check the sample table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cepvr.png)

suppose we have two unique ids for the users , 
e.g. those ids are 2 and 5, in your chat table you would have 2 as from_id as well as to_id and vise-e-versa.

If user 2 deletes the chat thread then insert 2 in hide_from,
now if user 5 deletes the chat thread then check if hide_from is not NULL && hide_from = 2, delete all the messages of 2 & 5

Comment: @shergill This is a better idea compare to Zerkms's logic. By this logic, You need to implement and manage only 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

Add a single flag status in which keep you can hold:

0 - unread

1 - read

2 - deleted by sender

3 - deleted by recipient

4 - spam, etc

Comment: I'd recommend to store it in `SET` datatype in mysql then

Comment: Or another table in which to hold the statuses, and this field to be just an FK to that

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: imho set will be much more performant (since for every messages query we will need to perform join).

Comment: I tend to dislike SETs - one reason is that if you have another value, you have to change DB structure, whereas with FKs, you simply make an insert - this is a strictly personal opinion - but of course, its a possible solution in this case

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: with second table you also have to alter table when you get another type of flag ;-) (because you need one more column to store it)

Comment: I meant, that with SETs you have to modify the DB structure when you have another value of the flag, not another flag type

Comment: @Tudor Constantin: cannot get you... :-S But anyway, doesn't matter ;-)